# Specifying the OS - Ansible

Tags: python, macos, ubuntu, package, ansible

I'm a newbie in `Ansible`, so I wrote a little ansible utility to install some package dependencies for a system I'm writing:

```
---

- hosts: all
  user: root
  tasks:
      - name: install requirements
        apt: name={{item}} state=latest update_cache=true
        with_items:
            - gcc
            - python-dev
            - python-setuptools
            - python-software-properties
```

The current supported environments are `Ubuntu`, `Red Hat` and `Mac OS X`. The current way this playbook is written it will only work in `Ubuntu (Debian)`. How can I have that part of the code be executed according to the OS? For `Ubuntu` it's `apt`, for `Red Hat` it's `yum` and for `Mac OS X` `brew`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The normal approach to this is to have an OS family specific task file that is conditionally included by checking the `ansible_os_family` fact.

So you may have a `main.yml` task file in your role that looks something like:

```
# Arbitrary task here, not needed but the point is you can have any generic tasks directly in main.yml
- name: get the date
  shell: `date`
  register: date

- include: debian.yml
  when: ansible_os_family == 'Debian'

- include: redhat.yml
  when: ansible_os_family == 'RedHat'
```

And then in `debian.yml` we have:

```
- name: install requirements
  apt: name={{item}} state=latest update_cache=true
  with_items:
      - gcc
      - python-dev
      - python-setuptools
      - python-software-properties
```

and in `redhat.yml` we have:

```
- name: install requirements
  yum: name={{item}} state=latest update_cache=true
  with_items:
      - gcc
      - python-dev
      - python-setuptools
      - python-software-properties
```

Obviously this allows you to set different dependency lists depending on the OS family as well.

If you wanted to you could also conditionally include OS family (or really anything you can check a fact for) specific vars like this:

```
- name: Include OS-specific variables.
  include_vars: "{{ item }}"
  with_first_found:
    - ../vars/{{ ansible_distribution | lower }}.yml
    - ../vars/{{ ansible_os_family | lower }}.yml
```

And then set your dependency lists in say `vars/debian.yml` like this:

```
python_dependencies:
  - gcc
  - python-dev
  - python-setuptools
  - python-software-properties
```

so now your `tasks/debian.yml` looks like:

```
- name: install requirements
  apt: name={{item}} state=latest update_cache=true
  with_items: python_dependencies
```

You can see a list of the OS's and their families by checking the source code [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/37ae2435878b7dd76b812328878be620a93a30c9/lib/ansible/module_utils/facts.py#L267) which has this dict of all the OS families:

```
# A list with OS Family members
OS_FAMILY = dict(
    RedHat = 'RedHat', Fedora = 'RedHat', CentOS = 'RedHat', Scientific = 'RedHat',
    SLC = 'RedHat', Ascendos = 'RedHat', CloudLinux = 'RedHat', PSBM = 'RedHat',
    OracleLinux = 'RedHat', OVS = 'RedHat', OEL = 'RedHat', Amazon = 'RedHat',
    XenServer = 'RedHat', Ubuntu = 'Debian', Debian = 'Debian', Raspbian = 'Debian', Slackware = 'Slackware', SLES = 'Suse',
    SLED = 'Suse', openSUSE = 'Suse', SuSE = 'Suse', SLES_SAP = 'Suse', Gentoo = 'Gentoo', Funtoo = 'Gentoo',
    Archlinux = 'Archlinux', Manjaro = 'Archlinux', Mandriva = 'Mandrake', Mandrake = 'Mandrake',
    Solaris = 'Solaris', Nexenta = 'Solaris', OmniOS = 'Solaris', OpenIndiana = 'Solaris',
    SmartOS = 'Solaris', AIX = 'AIX', Alpine = 'Alpine', MacOSX = 'Darwin',
    FreeBSD = 'FreeBSD', HPUX = 'HP-UX'
)
```

Comment: I don't have a mac so can't test it but if you run `ansible -i "mac-host," all -m setup` (where "mac-host" is the name of your OS X box) this will give all the facts about your "mac-host" machine that will hopefully give you some fact you can use to discern between it and another OS.

Comment: On `OS X` the `ansible_os_family` is `Darwin`

Comment: An updated mapping of family name to distributions is [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/9a9272305a7b09f84861c7061f57945ae9ad7090/lib/ansible/module_utils/facts/system/distribution.py#L464).

Comment: @pentavalentcarbon feel free to suggest an edit to the answer with the updated OS_FAMILY dict.